# Vim custom command to execute 'c""<Esc>P'

Tags: vim

I am trying to write a custom command that executes the following: `'c""<Esc>P'`, namely cut visually selected text, insert `""`and paste the cut text into the quotes.

I have tried the following:

```
command! -range Wq <line1>,<line2> execute 'c\"\"<Esc>P'
```

and some other variations of it, but none seem to work. How can I write a custom command to execute this command?

Comment: This would also be a good question on [vi SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/). If you don't mind using a plugin, [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) can be used to surround a selection with quotes.

Comment: I have used [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) but I want to try to write some of my own functions to replace some plugins, this being one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c""<Esc>P` (not `'c""<Esc>P'`) is a normal mode command. As such, it can't be executed via `:help :execute`, which deals with expressions that return Ex commands.

Outside of normal mode, normal mode commands can be executed with `:help :normal` but I don't think that's of any use, here, because a simple visual mode mapping would do the job neatly:

```
xnoremap <key> c""<Esc>P
```

which, I think, could be improved by removing the useless mode switching:

```
xnoremap <key> c"<C-r>""<C-c>
```

Comment: FWIW, what makes Surround so central to the workflow of so many users is that it provides operators in addition to visual mode mappings, like `ys<motion>`. You can do that on your own as well with `:help :map-operator`.